# Operations on the DiscriminatorValue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to map two classes to one table and use the inheritance to represent their relationships.

e.g. class A represents a general task with type id not equal to 3 or 4. class B is a more specific task with type id 3 or 4, the code can be seen like this,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="task_type_id",discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="not 3 or 4")
public class A {
    // some properties
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="task_type_id",discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="3 or 4")
public class B extends A {
    // some properties
}
```

How do I handle the DiscriminatorValue part with some operations like "not", "or"?

Comment: Huh? you are setting a VARCHAR column to "not 3 or 4" for an A object, and "3 or 4" for a B object. That is all a `@DiscriminatorColumn` will do. so no idea what you think of doing with "not" and "or", since this is not a query

Comment: I have edited the my question, the type of column is not VARCHAR but Int. What I am asking is what is the syntax for setting the discriminator value to 3 or 4, but not just one of the values. The class A doesn't have to be "not 3 or 4" it could be something like "not 2 or 3 or 4"

Comment: There is no such syntax. The value is what is put into the column. That is all there is. A class has a value, and from the retrieved value it knows the class ... serves a purpose. i.e a 1-1 correspondence between class and value. There is no 1-N correspondence between class and value possible

Comment: Then how should I solve this problem? Create two exactly same entities with discriminator value 3 and 4 respectively?

Comment: 1. Change the data in the column so that it maps to your model. or 2. Change your model to map to the data (bastardised model with dup'd classes).

Comment: This type id can not be changed since it is used in other places. I have several type ids to check, which means, I need to have many duplicated classes. So both are not feasible. So far the only possible solution I have is to create one more column to flag the class as A or B and use that column as the discriminator column